Message Queues IPC does not work properly
this code implements a simple client-server communication system using message queues in C.
local.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "sys/ipc.h"
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SEED 'g'    /* seed for ftok */
#define SERVER 1L   /* message for the server */

typedef struct{
    long    msg_to; /* placed in the queue for */
    long    msg_fm;  /* placed in the queue by */
    char    buffer[BUFSIZ];
}MESSAGE;

client.c:
#include "local.h" 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    key_t       key;
    pid_t       cli_pid;
    int         mid, n;
    MESSAGE     msg;
    static char m_key[10];

    cli_pid = getpid();
    
    if((key = ftok(".", SEED)) == -1){
        perror("Client: key generation");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((mid = msgget(key, 0)) == -1){
        mid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
        printf("%d", mid);
        
        switch (fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("Client: fork");
            exit(3);
        case 0:
            sprintf(m_key, "%d", mid);
            execlp("./server", "server", m_key, NULL);
            perror("Client: exec");
            exit(4);
        }
    }
    while(1){
        msg.msg_to = SERVER;
        msg.msg_fm = cli_pid;

        write(fileno(stdout), "cmd>", 5);
        memset(msg.buffer, 0x0, BUFSIZ);
        n = read(fileno(stdin), msg.buffer, BUFSIZ);
        if(n == 0){
            break;
        }


        if(msgsnd(mid, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0) == -1){
            perror("Client: msgsend");
            exit(5);
        }
        if((n = msgrcv(mid, &msg, sizeof(msg), cli_pid, 0)) != -1){
            write(fileno(stdout), msg.buffer, strlen(msg.buffer));
        }
    }
    msgsnd(mid, &msg, 0, 0);
    exit(0);
}


server.c:
#include "local.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int     mid, n;
    MESSAGE msg;
    void    process_msg(char *, int);

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s msq_id &\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (1) {
        if ((n=msgrcv(mid, &msg, sizeof(msg), SERVER, 0)) == -1 ) {
            perror("Server: msgrcv");
            exit(2);
        } else if (n == 0){
            break;
        } else {
            process_msg(msg.buffer, strlen(msg.buffer));
            msg.msg_to = msg.msg_fm;
            msg.msg_fm = SERVER;
            if (msgsnd(mid, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0) == -1 ) {
                perror("Server: msgsnd");
                exit(3);
            }
        }
    }
    msgctl(mid, IPC_RMID, (struct msqid_ds *) 0 );
    exit(0);
}

void process_msg(char *b, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        if (isalpha(*(b + i))){
            *(b + i) = toupper(*(b + i));
        }
    }
}

If i try to compile these files with using this commands:

gcc -o server server.c
gcc -o client client.c

and run the files:

./server 123 &
./client

Server is running and waiting,

(base) user@PC:~/UNIX/mqueues$ ./server 123 &
[2] 93463
(base) user@PC:~/UNIX/mqueues$ Usage: ./server msq_id &
/waiting for message here/

then i am trying to send a message from client. However i get that error message from client:

(base) user@PC:~/UNIX/mqueues$ ./client
cmd>hello
Client: msgsend: Invalid argument

I'm probably doing something wrong, I'd be very grateful if you could help me. Thanks.

One problem I've noticed is that you pass sizeof(MESSAGE) as the message size, but the size shouldn't include the mtype part (in your case, the msg_to part) so random bytes are copied between processes. This isn't related to your problem as far as I can tell. But just so you know.

Where does server.c initialize mid?

Can you add code to client.c that does a perror if mid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0660); is -1?

I've tried all suggestions here but it's still same. I get same "Invalid argument" error. Thanks for your reply.

See:
(base) user@PC:~/UNIX/mqueues$ ./server 123 &
[2] 93463
(base) user@PC:~/UNIX/mqueues$ Usage: ./server msq_id &
/waiting for message here/

That means that the server fails (message usage...).
The first error is that you require to pass 3 arguments to the server, but the last & is not part of the arguments to the command but used by the shell to launch the command in background.
Second error is that you must create the message queue at first in the server, prior to the call to msgrcv. If not, how the server would be able to read something?
Third, what logic is behind all of this? The client forks the server, but it seems that you want to run the server by hand too. Forget about running the server from the client.

in below code lines, msg_to is not set to SERVER. This appears to be problem.
        process_msg(msg.buffer, strlen(msg.buffer));
        msg.msg_to = msg.msg_fm;
        msg.msg_fm = SERVER;

If msg_to is not set, msg_type is invalid for msgsend() call and it can fail.

Thanks for your reply, however it's still same.

BUFSIZ is not set anywhere. Or is it missed from copy paste of code? Is  it possible to use hard coded mesg rather than stdin just to verify where is the problem.

BUFSIZ is not set anywhere you're right. Because it's coming from under stdio.h. Also i tried hard coded message, however i am getting the same error message.

BUFSIZ appears 8k bytes. Pls check what is maximum mesg size that can be used on msgsend() call. I find it is also 8k. for time being just verify with 20 bytes or some small buffer size instead of BUFSIZ in case we can narrow down this problem
